# How do I change the default alarm sound when creating an alarm with Siri?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, alarm

I picked a song for an alarm and now every  alarm that I create with Siri uses that song. I cannot change the default alarm song back to the default alarm sound. When I need to create an alarm manually I can see the default alarm sound, but every single time I  create an alarm with Siri then it reverts back to that one song. It's impossible to change the default alarm sound that Siri uses. I'm using iOS 10.2.

Comment: _It's impossible to change the default alarm sound that Siri uses_ I believe this is the answer. It may be frustrating, but I am certain that there is no way in changing the 'default' ringtone for new alarms. I think this is not a bad idea at all - maybe you should suggest this as a feature here: http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Comment: Well then how did I change the default  to a song to begin with?

Comment: Seems like I got your initial question wrong. So the song chosen by Siri for new alarms is not the iOS-default ringtone since you changed it once for another alarm. In that case this looks like a funny (well, apperently for you unfunny) bug. I'll try to reproduce this and report back.

Comment: Update: I reproduced the problem. When Siri sets the alarm I always get the song I used once before when setting an alarm. This definately seems to be a bug of iOS 10 and propably previous releases

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Did a hard reset (power and volume down until the Apple logo appeared. That'd be power and home button for all other non-7 devices.) It fixed the problem. It was driving me absolutely crazy.

Comment: What's wrong with just turning it off and on? Power + Home takes a screen shot.